# Reason for difference in power.prop.test and epiR::epi.sscompb results

Tags: r, sample-size, proportion

I was trying to rework the examples in Epidemiology Study Design and Data Analysis by Mark Woodward using R. Example 8.12 deals with calculation of sample size to test for a population proportion of 0.3 against the one sided alternative that it is greater than 0.32.

I tried two commands

```
power.prop.test(n = NULL, p1=0.3, p2=0.32, power =0.9, alternative = "one.sided")
epiR::epi.sscompb(n = NA, treat = 0.3, control = 0.32, power = 0.9, sided.test = 1 )
```

The results (sample size) given by the two functions are very different.

> Two-sample comparison of proportions power calculation
>
> ```
>           n = 9157.159
>          p1 = 0.3
>          p2 = 0.32
>   sig.level = 0.05
>       power = 0.9
> alternative = one.sided
> ```
>
> NOTE: n is number in *each* group

```
$n.total [1] 4568 
$n.treat [1] 2284 
$n.control [1] 2284
$power [1] 0.9
$lambda [1] 0.937500 1.066667
```

The result by epi.sscompb agrees with the value in the book.

Can someone tell me if there is an error in the code? If there is no error in the code, why are the results different?

Thanks, ajith

Answer (score 4):

`epi.sscompb` is meant for a one-sample proportion test, while `power.prop.test` is meant for a two-sample proportion test. This is why you get different results.

There is no equivalent to epi.sscompb in the R stats package (so you won't find any relevant function starting with "power.something.something"). If you're looking for testing epi.sscompb against another implementation of power calculation for one-sample proportion test in R, the R pwr package implements it:

```
library(pwr)
pwr.p.test(h=ES.h(p1=0.3, p2=0.32), sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.9, alternative = "less")
proportion power calculation for binomial distribution (arcsine transformation) 

              h = -0.04324895
              n = 4578.442
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.9
    alternative = less
```

Occasionally, as in your case, the results from pwr.p.test may be a bit different from epi.sscompb because epi.sscompb uses a formula based on an approximation, while pwr.p.test relies on the definition of power according to Jacob Cohen (*Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences*, 1988, pp. 179-213, in particular section 6.4.3 p. 208, and p. 549). When they disagree (generally not by much), pwr.p.test will generally give you a bit more power than epi.sscompb.

---

On the other hand, if you want a result in line with power.prop.test (two-sample case) in the epiR package, you should use epi.sscohortc as they [suggest in their documentation](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/epiR/html/epi.sscompb.html):

> Users are referred to the epi.sscohortc function which relates to the
> two-sample problem where neither proportion is known (or assumed, at
> least).

In your case, it gives:

```
epi.sscohortc(irexp1=0.3, irexp0=0.32, power = 0.90, r = 1, 
                  design = 1, sided.test = 1, finite.correction = FALSE, 
                  nfractional = T, conf.level = 0.95)
$n.total
[1] 18314.32
```

---

In short, here is a table summarizing the packages and their relevant functions, depending on the kind of test you plan to use:

|  | **epiR package** | **pwr package** | **stats package** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **power for one-sample proportion test** | epi.sscompb | pwr.p.test | N/A |
| **power for two-sample proportion test** | epi.sscohortc | pwr.2p.test | power.prop.test |

---

You may want to ask a separate question, in case you want to learn about the difference between a one-sample proportion test and a two-sample proportion test. Note that there are already some similar questions on this website about the difference between one-sample vs. two sample:

- [Proportion test: one sample or two sample?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430584/proportion-test-one-sample-or-two-sample)
- [hypothesis test one-sample vs two-sample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163543/hypothesis-test-one-sample-vs-two-sample)

Additionally, the `pwr` documentation offers [some examples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/vignettes/pwr-vignette.html) of the one-sample case vs. the two-sample case.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer. I understood the result of epi.sscompb because that is the same example from the textbook. What I don't understand is why power.prop.test is different from it. You say that "If you want a result in line with power.prop.test, where neither proportion is known, ...". But, how is both proportion not known when we use power.prop.test?  I am calling it with only n set as NA - power.prop.test(n = NULL, p1=0.3, p2=0.32, power =0.9, alternative = "one.sided").

Comment: @ajith I rewrote my answer, hopefully it will make things a bit clearer. It boils down to the difference between a one-sample proportion test, and a two-sample proportion test.